# Downloading image that has no ending (just php site like https://www.example.com/file.php?someparameterstuff)

Tags: python, selenium, imagedownload

**Using:** Python, Selenium

**Task:**
Downloading an image while using Selenium(Chrome) from a website that has no ending itself.
The file is an image but its loaded on an .php website like that:
https://www.example.com/file.php?someparameterstuff

The image has to be downloaded in the working directory as .png

**Problem:**

If i try it (tried several things like wget, urllib...) i get an empty file instead of the image.

**Help is much appreciated! :-)**